# Suppress unitest of gtest for Address sanitizer

Tags: c, clang, googletest, address-sanitizer

I'm running Address sanitizer on my unitests.
Cmake looks something like this:

```
    cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++-9 \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-9 \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS='-fsanitize=address -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope' \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-fsanitize=address -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope' \
```

The running command is

```
make clean
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_stack_use_after_return=1 make a.out -j
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_stack_use_after_return=1 LSAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=1 ./a.out
```

The unitests are written in gtest framework.

There is some unitest that by definition should make illegal access to out of array boundaries.
And I want to know how I can suppress this test

```
TEST_F(classA, testA) {
   some_struct a;
   a.p = 100;
   ASSERT_FALSE(&foo());
}
```

I saw here the option to suppress function but I don't know how to apply it on a unitest function
https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer

```
#if defined(__clang__) || defined (__GNUC__)
# define ATTRIBUTE_NO_SANITIZE_ADDRESS __attribute__((no_sanitize_address))
#else
# define ATTRIBUTE_NO_SANITIZE_ADDRESS
#endif
...
ATTRIBUTE_NO_SANITIZE_ADDRESS
void ThisFunctionWillNotBeInstrumented() {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how I can suppress this test

The easiest approach is probably to `#ifdef` it out:

```cpp
TEST_F(classA, testA) {
#if defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__)
   std::cerr << "classA.testA skipped under AddressSanitizer" << std::endl;
#else
   some_struct a;
   a.p = 100;
   ASSERT_FALSE(&foo());
#endif
}
```

Or you could `#ifdef` out the entire test:

```cpp
#if !defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__)
TEST_F(classA, testA) {
   std::cerr << "classA.testA skipped under AddressSanitizer" << std::endl;
   some_struct a;
   a.p = 100;
   ASSERT_FALSE(&foo());
}
#endif
```