# Address Sanitizer - suppress for gtest

Tags: googletest, suppress-warnings, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

Is possible to suppress unit test functions? I have address sanitizer in my project and I am getting reports with info about stack-buffer-overflow, which I want to supress.

It's already one stackoverflow page with similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195753/suppress-unitest-of-gtest-for-address-sanitizer#) , but solution for this question is not what I want to have (I don't want to disable test).

For example

```
TEST_F(classA, testA) {
  some_struct a;
  a.p = 100;
  ASSERT_FALSE(&foo());
}
```

I want to not use address sanitizer in this test. Test should be run but I don't want to have any address sanitizer report

Comment: Usually test runners run several tests built with different configs, for example test+coverage, test+address, test+ub, test+thread. Disabling one test case when it is built for address-sanitizer is a good solution, a disabled test case will run in other build configs.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting reports with info about stack-buffer-overflow, which I want to supress.

If you are going to just ignore errors, one solution is to not to test with address sanitizer at all.

> I want to not use address sanitizer in this test.

If you want to suppress sanitizer reports for this particular *test case*, while keeping the sanitizer for other test cases within this source file, using [disable_sanitizer_instrumentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#disable-sanitizer-instrumentation) attribute might do the trick.